# Prometheus & Grafana- To monitor or scrape the metrics from the azure app services without using azure monitoring tools

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, prometheus, grafana

Is there way to integrate azure app services with the Prometheus directly. We need to scrape the metrics of applications/devices hosted in the azure app service.
We can enable the app insight or azure monitoring tool and integrate them with the Grafana directly but here we want to by pass the azure monitoring tools.

Azure app service is paas and there is no way we can install any Prometheus agents directly. I wonder, if there are some ways to collect the metrics from those devices/box to monitor the health  of the system.

Any suggestions/solutions would be great to know.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question as you, but then found your question.

Did you found a solution? I've been searching for two hours now but cannot find a good guide anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app behind a load balancer in azure? If yes this isn't ideal from a Prometheus perspective. Its designed to have access to the instance directly.

The way I see it you have 2 options.

- Use OpenTelemetry collector to scrape your metrics and then export them to your Prometheus instance via the remote write exporter
- Or use the OTLP feature and send the metrics via the OTLP exporter

Either way you will need to expose a Prometheus endpoint that can be written to. Which may be something you'll need to consider.